# Flex - align horizontal AND vertical depending on screen size

Tags: css, flexbox

I am styling some social media icons on this site [artpenleystudios.com](http://artpenleystudios.com) . They are aligned okay at the moment, however I was hoping to use 'flex' properties to make it neater, specifically at certain screen sizes. I would like the 4 icons to display equally spaced, vertically and horizontally in a 2 x 2 grid and also display perfectly spaced and centred 4 x 1 when the screen size changes (via media queries). If anyone has a solution to this then I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Please provide your code in the question

Comment: Flexbox can't do that natively. Nor can any other layout method for that matter. If you provide a demo we might be able to offer workarounds

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you think about something like that here?

HTML:

```
<div class="master">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="item item-1">
      <img src="http://artpenleystudios.com/wp-content/themes/ap-studios/assets/images/instagram.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="item item-2">
      <img src="http://artpenleystudios.com/wp-content/themes/ap-studios/assets/images/facebook.svg" alt="Art Penley Studios - Facebook">
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="group">
    <div class="item item-3">
      <img src="http://artpenleystudios.com/wp-content/themes/ap-studios/assets/images/soundcloud.svg" alt="Art Penley Studios - Soundcloud">
    </div>
    <div class="item item-4">
      <img src="http://artpenleystudios.com/wp-content/themes/ap-studios/assets/images/vimeo.svg" alt="Art Penley Studios - Vimeo">
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.master {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: stretch; 
    padding: 20px;
}

.group {
   flex: 1 1 auto;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   align-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   background-color: white;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 60px;
}
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jannahody/pen/MyXJeb?editors=1100)

This is just a draft. Not sure I understand your question well.

Comment: If you don't understand the question, you should post a comment asking for clarification.  If you lack the reputation to comment, move on to the next question that you're able to answer.